# AndEngine - How to remove "Sprite Artifacts"?

Tags: android, game-engine, andengine, andengine-gles-2

I'm Using AndEngine Gles2.

I read about this "known issue" and solutions but they didn't work for me. The problem is that sometimes some of my sprite get a black border around them (the png files are perfectly fine).

[image: black border around the sprites]

I tried to extrude to pictures by using TexturePacker padding each image with 2px and try it with 1px extrude - didn't help tried to play with it 2 -3 px and didn't help.

I'm building my BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas in this way:

```
BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas gameTextureAtlas_7 = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(activity.getTextureManager(), 1024, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
```

and loading it:

```
gameTextureAtlas_7.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 1, 0));
gameTextureAtlas_7.load();
```

Some time I get the black border around them, Specealy after there is a google popup full screen ads , after closing it most of the sprite with the black border

What am I doing wrong?
How should I confige the BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder or the PNG files?

Comment: how many images r u putting in texture packer?

Comment: Only one.. i'm using it to add padding to a single png file

Comment: but texture packager is basically used to animating mutiple images in it...

Comment: I used it because i read this article regarding sptire artifacts and the solution was to add padding and use extrude with Texture Packer tool: 

http://www.matim-dev.com/texture-packer---get-rid-of-sprite-artefacts.html

Comment: post once this question on andengine blog ..will get more attention on the same